# Prevent 'jumpy' CSS transitions on elements with hinted (grid-fitted) text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply some CSS3 transitions on some headers in a website I'm working on, but there's something about transitions on elements that contain text that really bugs me: in browsers that apply hinting or grid-fit a font's glyphs (which I guess is most of them, bar perhaps Safari), there is a noticable 'jump' at the beginning and end of a transition where you can see that text is snapped back to the pixel grid, as demonstrated in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8csA9/20/ (part of this is probably a momentary 'blur'  due to filtering, but there's definitely some shape modification going on here, at least in FF and Chrome)

Normally I'd not even consider messing with the intricacies of font-rendering, but considering the glyphs are so large I feel that it doesn't really matter in this case, and was wondering if there is either a way to disable hinting, or some other way of making these transitions a bit smoother. Does anyone know if this can be done, and how?

PS: This question actually extends a bit beyond just transitions, just applying a static rotation also makes at least Firefox continue to hint the text, and the result ends up looking rather.. odd

PPS: There does seem to exist (or have existed) a '-webkit-font-smoothing' property, but the CSS3-fonts draft appears to have dropped the rule it was based on (font-smooth), and it seems it only ever worked on Chrome for the Mac

Comment: How intriguing! I would expect that font rendering would be handled by the OS natively and than transformed (like any other element would) - this is clearly not the case. I guess your main concern is the jumpiness of the transition rather than preference to a particular state - I wonder if you could trick the rendering engine into thinking the transition is ongoing?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm basically fine with the OS doing whatever it wants (or the user wants) with the text, it's just that I'd like to have the animation less jumpy/jittery. Initially I assumed just applying any sort of transform that makes grid-fitting less useful (like a very small rotation) would make hinting remain disabled, but sadly that doesn't seem to be that case. Your idea of tricking the browser into a continuing transition is interesting though

Comment: @aphax You are very much correct when you say all of that. It does happen. I have been trying to find a solution to that for quite sometime now, but the only thing I have been able to come up with is to have small transitions of these sort. I mean instead of moving something by `5px`, move it only by `1px`. It would seem less jerky that time. And I will say it again, there seems to by no way to fix this.

Answer (score 32):

Use **backface-visibility: hidden;**
**Update: webkit moz mz and the standard
http://jsfiddle.net/jugularkill/58S2z/4/

More on backface visibility:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Comment: I might be missing something, but in FF 12 this fiddle looks identical to the OP's one. There is still jitter and lag at the beginning and end.

Comment: Interesting, this does seem to make the jumpiness go away in Chrome 18, but not in Firefox 11. Looking at what this property is meant to do, it seems like this just happens to be a side-effect of how this is implemented in Chrome, but still, an interesting work-around

Comment: I know it is an old post, but for the sake of others... You must use the browser prefixes (-moz, -webkit,...) in order to make it work.

Comment: I've been fighting with this for a long time, thank you so much.

Comment: For me this is still/again 'jumpy' on Firefox 29.0.

Answer (score 6):

This worked like a charm for me.  I added "backface-visibility:hidden" (plus major browser prefixes) to the elements with the transition property, and it fixed the jump/jitter I was experiencing during the transition.  I tested in Firefox, IE (9/10) and Chrome.

One thing I noticed though: Make sure you add the property to the element's natural state, as opposed to the  pseudo-class (e.g. hover, active...) of an element.

Answer (score 5):

For me I found that I needed to add both `backface-visibility: hidden` and `transform-style: preserve-3d` to the element that contained jumpy content.

For example:

```
.element-with-jumpy-content {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap you can use this class:

```
.backface-visibility(hidden);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` or `transform: translateZ(0);` often helps to fix transition bugs, because it forces browser to use hardware-accelerated 3D transitions.