# text rendering going blured on hover in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, text, text-rendering

I have a problem with text going blured on hover Version 27.0.1453.110 Chrome Mac OS X, but maybe on Windows too.

Link to see is here - http://hqm.gr/jam-for-fun-2013-report - hover on the video gallery bottom menu

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get blurred text on Chrome 27.0.1453.110 on Windows.

Comment: I'm getting it on 28.0.1500.44 beta-m.  Try to disable the css transitions and see what happens. I'll guess that it has something to do with your transitions and opacity on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't give you the reason why this works, but you need to add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the element that is undertaking the CSS3 transitions

(kudos go to @JugularKill for his answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853317/681807))

The reason this is particularly funny (to me at least) is that `backface-visibility` in Chrome is [considered broken/buggy](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backface-visibility/)!

So the solution, in your particular case, would be:

```
.videogallery .navCon .navigationThumb {
    ....
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get blurred here on Chrome 27.0.1453.110 on iMac. It does in fact compresses the text height or size for one second when I mouseover or mouseout, but then returns to normal size quickly. Check your definitions for font / text size.

I just checked your css and the `text-shadow:` is being applied on hover, but is broken in two lines:

```
        .main-navigation a:hover,
        .widget-post.pm-first a:hover,
        .ticker-content a:hover,
        .utilities ul li a:hover,
        .cat-tabs ul li a:hover
        {color:#ffffff; text-shad
        ow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);}
```