# Firefox transition font rendering

Tags: css, firefox

On hover the `<h3>`'s position is changed via translate3d with the use of a transition. When the transition is done the font shows bolder than on the start of the transition. This problem only seems to occur in Firefox.

I have created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57rwmbo6/3/

I found one stack overflow item regarding to the same problem. But the provided solutions don't work.
[Prevent 'jumpy' CSS transitions on elements with hinted (grid-fitted) text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707202/prevent-jumpy-css-transitions-on-elements-with-hinted-grid-fitted-text)

Is there a known fix for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Just tested it on Firefox ESR (24.8), and it looked identical to Chrome 39.  What version of FF are you on?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using Firefox 31.0.